# How to save changes to a python object?

Tags: python, object, dictionary, pickle, savechanges

I have a Python dictionary of objects from a class that I have created in one file. It is of the form `{string : object}`, with several key, value pairs.

My goal is to do something in a method in a separate file that changes an attribute of certain objects in the dictionary and to save those changes to those objects while keeping them within the dictionary.

I've tried using pickle, but it doesn't seem to save the changes to the objects within the dictionary.

Basic Idea of what I'm doing right now and what is wrong with it:

**File #1:**

```
class A:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0

a = A()
dict = {"Test" : a}
pickle.dump(dict, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

**File #2:**

```
dict = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
dict["Test"].value += 1
print(dict["Test"].value)
pickle.dump(dict, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

So when I run File #2 the first time, it should print `1`, and it does
but when I run File #2 the second time, I want it to print `2`, but it prints `1` again because the change to the value was not saved.

It could be that I am using pickle incorrectly...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> Note that none of the class’s code or data is pickled

See [pickling class instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) for the right way to do it.

Also `class A` does not exist in the unpickling environment, that can't be a good thing, class are unpickeled by name if I read the doc right.

BTW I'd use `json` over `pickle` so you can open the file between two runs and inspect it yourself to understand what happen. There's a few advantages to use `json` over `pickle`, and a few to use `pickle` over `json`, here's a [comparison between pickle and json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json).

Oh, and, avoid naming your variables `dict` or any existing builtins, it shadows them and can lead to very strange behaviors.